# Regularisation parameter in On-line ridge regression

Tags: r, regression

I have the pseudo-code, but still I'm struggling to implement ridge regression in on-line mode. I'm using dual form, so I don't know how to update a, alongside other difficulties. The pseudo-code is [here](http://onlineprediction.net/?n=Main.RidgeRegression).

So far I've written the following:

Input is: x(1),...,x(m) m vectors and y(1),...,y(m) targets.

Output is: f(x[1](http://onlineprediction.net/?n=Main.RidgeRegression)),...,f(x[m]) model predictions

```
Ridge.Regression<-function(m,x){

b<- rep(0,m)

A<- a * diag(nrow(x)) 

for (t in 1:m){

    pred[,t]<- b * (solve(A) %*% x[t,])

    A<- A + x[t,] %*% x[t,] 

    b<- y[t] * x[t,]

    b<- b + (y[t] * x[t,])

    return(pred)}}
```

What I have done above does not work. Something wrong with initialisation of input vector b and matrix A?

It does not make sense to have a constant value of the parameter a. We use cross-validation in batch learning. What to use in on-line learning?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "does not work"? How are you testing this function? Plus, if you have questions about statistical methodologies, you'd be better off asking at [stats.se].

Comment: Ridge.Regression(m=200,x=data) and a = 2, I get non-conformable arguments in solve(A) %*% x[t,]. x I used has 1 column and 200 rows and same for y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some dimension mismatches in your code.
Based on my understanding you have a sample size of `n`
and `m` predictors or regressors to choose from.

## Lets go step by step.

1. I referred your link and gamma is a 1 X 1 value.
   In stead you have pred[,t] as as n X 1 . You may refer to `pred[,t]` as `pred[t]` You also have the vector `b` with dimensions m by 1 in stead of
   n by 1.
2. Also notice that your initial choice of the matrix A is
   diagonal. Please do not use `solve` to invert a diagonal matrix.
   `solve` is ideal to use if your matrix does not have any
   special structure. `solve` is an expensive operation for R
   to perform.
3. Next when updating A you need to realize that A is an n by n matrix
   The initial matrix value is diagonal with the tuning parameter. When
   your write `x[t,] %*% x[t,]` you are performing matrix multiplication
   of two n by 1 vectors The orders do not commute. In stead try writing
   `x[t,] %*% t(x[t, ])` This ensures you create an n by n matrix.
4. b is not being updated in the right manner. What your are doing is
   replacing the initial vector of zeros and updating it by `y[t] * x[t,]`
   You are then updating b again. The third line in your for
   loop looks redundant to me.

## Why don't you try this piece of code

```
set.seed(54) # a random seed
n <- 100     # sample size
m <-40      # number of predictors 

# create n X m design matrix
x <- matrix(runif(n), nrow = n, ncol = m)

# Initialize b with zero vector
b <- rep(0, n) 

y <- rnorm(m) # m by 1 vector

a <- 5     # choice of tuning parameter depends on user
A <- diag(a, n)
pred <- rep(0, n) #initialize output
  Ridge.Regression<-function(m, x, b, a, n){
      #Arguments X must be a design matrix
      # m is the number of predictors
      # b is n X 1 vector
      # n is the sample size
      # a is the tuning parameter
      # Function returns predicted values.


  ainv <- (1/a)
  Ainv <- diag(ainv, n)
  for (t in 1:m){

    pred[t] <- t(b) %*% (Ainv %*% x[,t])

    A <- A + x[,t] %*% t(x[, t])
    Ainv <- solve(A) # using solve since A may not have special sturcture

    b <- b + (y[t] * x[,t]) # update b
    }
  return(pred)
  }
```

I hope this is a good answer to you.

Comment: I still can't get the answer. I get Error  Ainv %*% x[t, ] : non-conformable arguments!